# Open Refine Error Uploading Data?

Tags: openrefine

I'm trying google refine out to address name disambiguation in my data. 
Whenever I upload a CSV, however, I keep getting this error.

I've been following the tutorial at this link [Tutorial](http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/OpenRefine_Tutorial)

```
Error uploading data
.import-temp/1405348781604/raw-data/spreadsheet/ccc (No such file or directory)
```

I also came across this in my google search, naming a similar problem I'm facing.

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/670

But I don't know how to fix the issue. Am I supposed to go into the source code and edit the lines mentioned? If so, can someone please give me some directions about how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error message is that you don't have write access for the folder that contains the OpenRefine files.
I first had the files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenRefine\`. Then I moved the folder to `D:\Documents\OpenRefine` and the error disappeared.